# How to fix the bar chart display in R for Hindi characters?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I am trying to do NLP using Udpipe for getting a word cloud in Hindi on a Mac. When I tokenize the Hindi text it displays in Rstudio. But when I try to take the words and plot a bar chart it displays square boxes. 
How do I solve this issue?

[image]

```
hindimodel <- udpipe_download_model(language = "hindi")
hindimodel <- udpipe_load_model(file = "hindi-hdtb-ud-2.3-181115.udpipe")
anno<-udpipe_annotate(hindimodel, "बाजार में एक नई तरह की पाजेब चली है। पैरों में पड़कर वे बड़ी अच्छी 
मालूम होती हैं। उनकी कड़ियां आपस में लचक के साथ जुड़ी रहती हैं कि पाजेब का मानो निज का आकार कुछ नहीं है, जिस 
पांव में पड़े उसी के अनुकूल ही रहती हैं। पास-पड़ोस में तो सब नन्हीं-बड़ी के पैरों में आप वही पाजेब देख लीजिए। एक ने 
 पहनी कि फिर दूसरी ने भी पहनी। देखा-देखी में इस तरह उनका न पहनना मुशन")

anno <- data.frame(anno)
anno$token #displays the Hindi text in Rstudio here
anno$upos

library(utf8)
library(lattice)

stats <- subset(anno, upos %in% c("NOUN")) 
stats <- txt_freq(stats$token)
stats$key <- factor(stats$key, levels = rev(stats$key))
##does not display the Hindi characters in the bar chart below
barchart(key ~ freq, data = head(stats, 20), col = "cadetblue",
         main = "Most occurring nouns", xlab = "Freq")
```

Comment: What is your locale (as in `Sys.getlocale(“LC_CTYPE”) `). Change it to another locale https://support.apple.com/kb/PH25082?locale=en_US&viewlocale=en_US

Comment: When I try the above command it is "en_US.UTF-8"
When I try 
`Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Hindi")`
it gives the following error
Warning message:
`In Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Hindi") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "Hindi" cannot be honored`